# issue with gradle 2.0.0 and DataBinding

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-studio-2.0, android-gradle-2.0

Recently i have updated Android studio from 1.5.1 to 2.0, after updation it asked me to use latest gradle i.e. `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0`

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"
}
```

But after updating it is showing error with DataBinding plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding' //error on this line
```

Error message :

```
Error:(2, 0) Cause: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
Open File
```

I have not used any apache library or any deprected apache classes.

***UPDATE :***

Harshad's answer helped me, so final conclusion is we don't need to add those plugins with `gradle 2.0.+`

`classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1"` **remove**
`apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'` **remove**

Comment: see my answer if this helpful to you.

Comment: The Android Gradle Plugin already includes data binding since version 1.5.0. You don't need to use the extra Gradle Plugin anymore. You didn't have to do that for quite a long time now. You can activate databinding in your build.gradle simply by setting a flag, see @Harshads answer.

Comment: @XaverKapeller thanks for explaination, but recently i was using 1.5.0 and i have to add that plugin, i think after 2.0.0 we dont need to add those plugins additionaly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be help you.

You can just remove these two lines of code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.databinding'
```

And this one in buildscript's dependencies:

```
classpath 'com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc1'
```

Then add the dataBinding section to your build.gradle like this.

```
buildscript {
    ...
}

android {
    ...

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    ...

}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

Comment: ohh yes, that helps, now we dont need to add those plugins. Thanks