# Error:Cause: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils occurs when trying to configure databinding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I have Android Studio 2.3 and Gradle plugin 2.3.0 installed. When I try to configure data-binding in `build.gradle` file as,

```
android {
....
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
}
```

and when I sync it, I get the following error:

> Error:Cause: org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils

I tried adding `commons io` library but still it shows the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36491390/issue-with-gradle-2-0-0-and-databinding

Comment: Do you also have an error? Or only the cause of it?

Comment: i am following the same way as https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html suggests..not used any plugin or dependency @IntelliJ Amiya

Comment: its an error while syncing gradle..@tynn

Comment: @TusharGogna: regarding your edit, please do not add code formatting to names of software items, they are not code. Android Studio, Gradle, etc become [proper nouns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun) and so just need capital letters. Thanks.

Comment: try it with `Invalidate caches/restart`

Comment: tried that too for the first time when error occurred.. @Ravi

Comment: don't know what was the cause... upgraded to android studio 2.3.1 and now it works like charm. Thanks anyways to all.